# Format messages for javascript form evaluation

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to develop a simple extension for Safari Firefox and Chrome in wich a form is presented to a user on a pop-up and after being filled out is locally evaluated and the response to the user is defined on that evaluation.
The original form can be found on: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/86545493/Waze/Calculadora.html

I have also already been able to create a working safari extension that can be downloaded here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/86545493/Waze/Extensions/WRTC.safariextz
but my problems starte when trying to create the chrome extension.

I followed the tutorial for creating a first extension and was able to create a button and load the form as a popup. However the security restrictions do not allow my form to run. From what I have understood by reading the Developers Guide what I need is to separate the javascript in its own file and call it from the popup file. However the language of the documents is too technical for me (med student) and I have been unable to understand the proper way to format the messages that should be used. Here is the current status for my code:

popup.html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Calculadora de Tipo de Camino</h1>
<form id="Calle" target="_self">
    Cruceros <select id="cruceros">
     <option value=1>Glorietas</option>
     <option value=1>Rotondas</option>
     <option value=1>Sem&aacuteforos</option>
     <option value=0 selected>Sin Control</option>
     <option value=2>Sin Cruceros</option>
    </select></br>
    Carriles <select id="carriles">
        <option value=1 selected>1</option>
        <option value=2>2</option>
        <option value=3>3 o m&aacutes</option>
    </select></br>
    Sentidos Separados f&iacutesicamente o parte de par vial <input type="checkbox" id="sentidos"></br>
    Con Laterales o Acotamiento <input type="checkbox" id="laterales"></br>
    Entradas y Salidas delimitadas <input type="checkbox" id="ramps"></br>
    Avenida, Boulevard, o Circuito <input type="checkbox" id="name"></br>
    Es Carretera
    <select id="carretera">
        <option value=0 selected>No</option>
        <option value=1>Municipal</option>
        <option value=2>Estatal</option>
        <option value=3>Federal</option>
    </select> Revisar en: <a href="http://petra.sdg.mx/sigcsi/" target="_blank">SCT</a></br>
    Tiene topes <input type="checkbox" id="topes"></br>
    </br>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="textR()">Calcular Puntos</button>
<hr><p id="resultn"></p>
<p id="resultt"></p>
</body>
```

popup.js

```
function textR()
{var cru=document.getElementById("cruceros").value;
if (cru==0){crun=0}
else if (cru==1){crun=1}
else{crun=2}
var carr=document.getElementById("carriles").value;
if (carr==1){carrn=0}
else if (carr==2){carrn=1}
else{carrn=2}
sen=(document.getElementById("sentidos").checked==true)?1:0;
lat=(document.getElementById("laterales").checked==true)?1:0;
ram=(document.getElementById("ramps").checked==true)?1:0;
av=(document.getElementById("name").checked==true)?1:0;
var hw=document.getElementById("carretera").value;
if (hw==1){hwn=1}
else if (hw==2){hwn=2}
else if (hw==3){hwn=3}
else{hwn=0}
saluden=(document.getElementById("topes").checked==true)?1:0;
var r=crun+carrn+sen+lat+ram+av+hwn+saluden;
document.getElementById("resultn").innerHTML=(r+" puntos");
if (r<2){rt='Street'}
else if (r<4){rt='<span class="pstreet">Primary Street'}
else if (r<7){rt='<span class="mihw"> Minor Highway '}
else if (r<9){rt='<span class="mahw"> Major Highway '}
else {rt='<span class="fw"> Freeway '}
document.getElementById("resultt").innerHTML=(rt);
}
```

Could you please tell me the proper syntax to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up putting `document.getElementById("calcButton").addEventListener("click", textR);` at the end of popup.js and had to move `<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>` to the end of the popup.html.

I found this article usefull: [Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856140/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-addeventlistener-of-null)

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate Inline code `onclick="textR()"` and add it in `popup.js` as shown here

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click",textR);
```

Comment: I actually had to use getElementById instead since "ByTagName" produced some other error, I also had to make more changes to the code.