# JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot call method 'getBoundingClientRect' of null

Tags: java, gwt

When using [gwt-tour library](https://github.com/eemi2010/gwt-tour) in a Errai/GWT application this error is thrown:

> com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot
>   call method 'getBoundingClientRect' of null   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
>     at com.eemi.gwt.tour.client.GwtTour._createCallOut(GwtTour.java)    at
>   com.eemi.gwt.tour.client.GwtTour.createCallOut(GwtTour.java:106)  at
>   app.client.local.UIController$1.execute(UIController.java:46)     at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Task$.executeScheduled$(SchedulerImpl.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.runScheduledTasks(SchedulerImpl.java:228)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.flushPostEventPumpCommands(SchedulerImpl.java:388)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Flusher.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:78)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.execute(SchedulerImpl.java:138)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>     at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

What does this error implies:

```
JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot call method 'getBoundingClientRect' of null
```

Comment: xybrek ,This might be helpful.this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856140/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-addeventlistener-of-null

Comment: @Baadshah: except GWT's `onModuleLoad` always run at `DOMContentLoad` or later (never before). Note that it might be a similar issue though: using an element that's not yet attached to the document, so gwt-tour cannot find it.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Hmmm looks like that is the cause, as the button it looks for is defined in JBoss Errai template