# Event tracking a button with analytics.js

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, analytics.js

I'm using the new GA analytics.js to track my website, that triggers just  fine. I'm trying to track a button for clicks (linking to an external website), making sure it opens in a new window so we have the time to track it.

```
<button class="knapp" id="b2" onclick="window.open('https://site.com');" 
target="_blank" type="button">Text</button>
```

According to [googles guidelines,](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) I can now use JS to track this.

Hence, I updated the code to match my button ID and events, then placed it in my header.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var downloadLink = document.getElementById('b2');
addListener(downloadLink, 'click', function() {
ga('send', 'event', 'External_link', 'click', 'KL-FB');
});

function addListener(element, type, callback) {
 if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, callback);
 else if (element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
}
</script>
```

However, it doesn't trigger at all. I have a "normal" event tracker on a normal link that triggers just fine, but from what I can see in my console this doesn't even try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. Your `addListener` function in the `<head>` is running before the element `b2` is rendered. There are a few options to solve this: Put scripts in bottom of page, call attach code on load, or wrap it in a jQuery `document.ready`. There is a good [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856140/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-addeventlistener-of-null) on this.
2. Your inline `onclick` event on the button is getting fired prior to the event sending. Use [google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced) `hitCallback` function to send the user to the next page *after* ga has received the event.

That would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var downloadLink = document.getElementById('b2');
    addListener(downloadLink, 'click', function() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'External_link', 'click', 'KL-FB', {
            'hitCallback': function(){
                document.location = 'https://site.com';
            }
        });
    });

function addListener(element, type, callback) {
 if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, callback);
 else if (element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, and sorry for not thinking about the order of things.