# Can I call different JavaScript <script> tags depending on which button a user clicks?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to call different external js files depending on which button a user clicks. The files are each in a different folder.

Each user on the system I'm building has a folder and each contains a file called chat.js.

I'm trying to allow the user to click on a users name in order to load their specific file.

You can see below that I've used "onclick" - I know this is wrong but when I used a click event I kept getting the error:

```
Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

in the console even though my IDs were identical across the HTML and JavaScript.

Changing to to onclick has fixed that error but it now gives me the error:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/confirm/dave/chat.js.
```

"dave" being the name of the folder relating to the username.

You can see my code below:

```js
/* link.js */
function runScript1() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = user1 + "/chat.js.";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  return false;
}

function runScript2() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = user2 + "/chat.js.";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script>
  var user1 = "<?php echo $user1; ?>";
  var user2 = "<?php echo $user2; ?>";
</script>
<script src="link.js"></script>
<!-- User 1 -->

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" id="chatBtnMain" onclick="runScript1()">
  Chat to
  <span class='nickname'>
                    <?php echo $user1;?>
                </span>
</button>

<!-- User 2 -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3" id="chatBtnMain" onclick="runScript2()">
  Chat to
  <span class='nickname'>
                    <?php echo $user2;?>
                </span>
</button>
```

Can anyone see why I'd be getting the error "GET"?
The folder and file definately exist and they're in the same directory as the js file and the php file

Comment: what's with `chat.js.`? the final period is definitely odd. is that really the name of your files? shouldn't it be `chat.js`, no trailing `.`? urls aren't english sentences. they don't need to end with punctuation.

Comment: shud b easy.. get the response via ajax, create a script element and append, like the way most of the analytic scripts do..

Comment: Related to your other problem: [Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856140/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-addeventlistener-of-null)

Comment: Why are you loading specific chat.js files? What's unique / specific about them? Feels like there should be a better way to do what you want....

Comment: I feel a bit daft with the period at the end. That's just something I missed, It's got rid of the "GET" error but still doesn't seem to link the file properly. I have more onpage javascript down before the closing body tag which contains functions relating to the js files i'm trying to access and they're are coming up as undefined. The reason there's different chat.js files is that I'm using a bit of JSON/AJAX to pull different php files depending on the user. There may well be an easier way to get what I want but I don't know any other ways

Comment: If you got the names correct, it seems like it should work. Maybe you should post an example of what's in `chat.js`.

Comment: Hi Barmar, Yeah, using @MarcB 's answer I managed to get it working. Then it was just a case of moving my scripts around so they're called in the right order. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: This feels like 100% the wrong approach.  As others have asked, what's in the user-specific chat files?  Seems like a better question would be about how to architect your system in a smart way.

Comment: different files for different users is weird. it's php. it can spit out any data you want. just have ONE script, and pass in a parameter: `<script src="foo.php?userID=123">`

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll give that a shot too. I need it to link to specific .txt files relating to the user also. It was also an attempt to stop the root folder from becoming cluttered as each new user is given a .txt file. So I could have one php file with the link to the text file having a similar structure as you mentioned above but then the root folder may end up full of .txt files. I'm making an adaptation of [this](https://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/). I'm also fairly new to PHP so I appreciate all the constructive criticism.