# Browser-Action / ChromeExtention/EventLIstener (How to ensure that the content of the form is submitted successfully)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

I'm working on my first Chrome extension and I still can't solve this problem. The idea behind my extension is simple. You type in an ID into the form and hit search. This triggers a new window popping up with a long URL. In the middle of this URL, you should see the ID that we typed into via the form. What happens instead is a new window is popping up, loading a long URL and instead of the number you can see "[object%20Event]". In other words, I want the ID submitted and merge it with two other strings - that all together constitute the URL.

Any ideas? Any help is much appreciated! Many thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ChromeFacebook.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1 id="title"> Enter ID: </h1>
<h2 id="paragraphs"> Comments </h2>

<form id="form1">
<input type="text" size="60" placeholder="Photos-commented"><input 
type="submit" value="Search">   
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var id = document.getElementById('form1');

function a(id) {
window.open("https://www.facebook.com/search/str/" + id + "/photos-
commented", "a") 
{;

document.getElementById('form1').addEventListener('submit', a);
```

Comment: there's no element with id "num1" obviously

Comment: @Kos Thanks for your quick reply! Yes, you're right. I've changed it and it still gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at ChromeFacebook.js" the error refers to line 7 of my JS

Comment: update your question with your changes then

Comment: I see, try putting your `ChromeFacebook.js` before `</body>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856140/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-addeventlistener-of-null)

Comment: I put ChromeFacebook.js before </body>, however, whenever I click on the extension it automatically opens the URL without giving me a chance to type in a number.
Also, thanks for the link - I willcheck it

Comment: HI @Kos, after reading the link you sent me, I tried using 
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
     }); instead of jQuery. Still doesn/t work. I will try jQuery next. If you have another idea, please let me know!

Comment: You are calling the `a` function instead of assigning it to the listener. In the last line, change `addEventListener("click",a(num1));` for `addEventListener("click",a);`. Consider also giving more meaningful names to functions and not naming global and local variables with the same name (in your case `num1`). One last thing: you may want to pass the function `a` the `textContent` of the form or the `value` of the `input` instead of the whole NodeElement.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko Thanks for your help! I revised the script accordingly. Please see updated code in original post:

The problem is now that I can't pass the output of the form into the string in window.open(). Whenever I click on submit, the window opens, however, i can see in the URL - it says "/[object%20Event]" . Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the argument of your listener function to create the URL, but the argument of the listener function is an [Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). If you want to use the value of the first text `input`, that is what you need to state in your code. For example:

```
function myEventListener() {
  window.open("https://www.facebook.com/search/str/" + document.querySelector("#form1 input").value + "/photos-
commented", "_blank");
}

document.getElementById('form1').addEventListener('submit', myEventListener);
```